# A largest lattice of a given Vapnik-Chervonekis dimension

Tags: lattice-theory, learning-theory

> Prove (or disprove) that a largest lattice of [Vapnik-Chervonekis dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) at most $k$ which has at most $n\cdot k$ join-irreducible and $n\cdot k$ meet-irreducible elements is the distributive lattice $L=\prod_{n=1}^kC_n$, where $C_n$ is the $(n+1)$-element chain.

(The problem was posed on 06.01.2018 by Bogdan Chornomaz on [page 88](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?page=88) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka).

Award for a solution: *a bottle of fine whiskey*).

Comment: I do like your project. But users here usually also answer some questions by others ;)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Sorry for this excessive activity. This is just a singularity -- for each problem I had to add links to the pages of the book (for convenience of the reader). So I make those massive edits. This will end soon (only 3 more question remained unedited -- and the system does not allow to edit more than 10 posts at one day). Then I promise to make a long break :)

Comment: I have nothing against edits at all. It is just that you make yourself sort of a one way user by only asking (very interesting) questions :D